# Laravel: Автоматическое определение локали на мультиязычном сайте

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Достаточно ли для автоматического определения и установки локали добавить тэгу `html` атрибут `lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}`? Или же нужно ещё какие-то настройки прописать, чтобы локаль автоматически определялась и в зависимости от неё страница отображалась на нужном языке?

И ещё (не думаю, что это стоит выносить в отдельный вопрос): как протестировать с локального сервера корректное отображение нужного языка для каждой локали? Естественно, по умолчанию будет отображаться тот язык, который соответствует главной локали, указанной в `config/app.php`, но как проверить корректность отображения страниц с другими локалями?

Предполагается, что на сайте доступно более двух языков (то есть помимо основной и fallback локалей есть и другие).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Достаточно ли для автоматического определения и установки локали
>   добавить тэгу html атрибут lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}?

Нет, не достаточно. 
Для определения языка пользователя можно использовать суперглобальный массив $_SERVER, а точнее — его элемент $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] в нем описываются предпочтения клиента относительно языка.

После этого, через фасад App задаешь локаль по умолчанию 
App::setLocale($locale);

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!